# How can I make a script echo something when it is paused?

Tags: bash, signals, trap

I am pausing a terminal script with `SIGSTOP`, and I want it to print a message that it is being paused.

- Since I can't trap the `SIGSTOP`, I've tried sending a `SIGUSR1` before the `SIGSTOP` and trapping that, but the command I put in the trap ends up being executed after the script is resumed.
- If I put a `sleep` between the `SIGUSR1` and the `SIGSTOP`, the trap command gets executed, but the script then runs a bit before the `SIGSTOP` is received.

Is there a way I can externally tell my script to echo "I'm being paused", then *immediately* stop?

Edit:
I'm using bash. My test script is just:

```
trap "echo Paused" SIGUSR1
trap "echo Restarted" SIGCONT

while : ; do
    echo `date`
    sleep 1
done
```

I call this like "./blah.sh".

My control script is:

```
script_id=`pidof -x blah.sh`
kill -SIGUSR1 $script_id
sleep 0.5
kill -SIGSTOP $script_id

sleep 2

script_id=`pidof -x blah.sh`
kill -SIGCONT $script_id
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code (ideally, just a _minimal_ example that reproduces the issue) you are using so we can see how you trap what etc. That will help us help you. Also make sure to tell us i) the shell you are using, ii) how you run the script (`script.sh` or `bash script.sh` or whatever) and iii) how you send the signals (`kill`? Ctrl+Z? something else?)

Answer (score 9):

you should use `SIGTSTP` instead of `SIGSTOP`. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html#:%7E:text=The%20SIGSTOP%20signal%20stops%20the,handled%2C%20ignored%2C%20or%20blocked.&text=The%20SIGTSTP%20signal%20is%20an,can%20be%20handled%20and%20ignored.):

> The `SIGSTOP` signal stops the process. **It cannot be handled, ignored,**
> **or blocked.**
>
> The `SIGTSTP` signal is an interactive stop signal. **Unlike `SIGSTOP`, this**
> **signal can be handled and ignored.**

Here's an example:

```
paused() {
    echo PAUSED
    kill -SIGSTOP $$ # This signal cannot be handled. Here the script is actually paused.
    echo CONTINUED
}
trap 'paused' SIGTSTP
```

Example:

```
$ ./test_pause.sh & disown
[1] 18852
$ kill -TSTP 18852
PAUSED
$ kill -CONT 18852
CONTINUED
```